# My Language Certificate was not included in my UK visa application. Can it be rejected for this?

Tags: immigration, uk-visa, application-status

I uploaded all documents to the VFS Global platform, and according to the checklist I had to bring only two documents to the biometric appointment: my passport and my language certificate, so I did, but once there the VFS guys said they only required my passport and, if I wanted to include the certificate they would charge me for sending additional documentation. I explained this was in the checklist document but they kept saying it was “additional”, so I didn’t enclosed it. After the appointment I checked my uploaded documentation I didn’t find the certificate anywhere. Is there any way to rectify this and just send the certificate to be added to my application, or should I just expect refusal?

Comment: If you don’t qualify for an exception the application could be refused or the ECO might contact you to request it if the application is otherwise in order. Are you sure it is necessary in your case https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/knowledge-of-english? If yes, I would contact VFS immediately to explain what happened and ask what action can be taken.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but unfortunately they don’t provide any phone number to reach them. There are a couple of email addresses but they reply with generic or automatic responses only.

Comment: Ok, what about contacting UKVI? https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk

Comment: Yes, I’ve just sent them an email. I’ll keep you posted. Thanks